# DragDrop in PictureBox - DragEnter never gets called

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, picturebox, mousemove

I want use `DragDrop` in my `PicureBox`es but `DragDrop()` and `DragEnter()` methods are never called.

I created method `MouseMove` and in this method I called `DoDragDrop()` which should call `DragDrop()` and `DragEnter()`. `MouseMove` is called but rest not.

Form constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.AllowDrop = true;
}
```

This is create in constructor of `PictureBox`:

```
this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(ttile_DragDrop);
this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(ttile_DragEnter);
this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(ttile_MouseMove);
```

And my method:

```
public void ttile_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
   int i = 0;
}

public void ttile_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
   int i = 0; 
}

public void ttile_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
      ((PictureBox)sender).DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.All);
   }
}
```

Comment: instead of `MouseMove` try using `MouseDown`

Comment: It is completely unclear what kind of drag operation you are trying to implement.  Your first snippet suggests you want to drop on the form, the second suggests you want to drop on the picture box.  You seem to have *two* methods named ttile_DragEnter.  The one you posted is wrong, it doesn't set e.Effect.  Sure this won't work.

Comment: Why would you like to use Drag enter?

Comment: @Mobstaa I just drag one Image from PictureBox to another PictureBox.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue. The problem is that you have `AllowDrop` for the form, but not the picture. And for a reason I ignore, `AllowDrop` is not a member of `PictureBox`.

The trick that worked for me was to replace

```
this.AllowDrop = True;
```

by

```
((Control)myPictureBox).AllowDrop = True;
```

where `myPictureBox` is my instance of `PictureBox`.

Comment: Crazy.. this worked for me (thanks for the tip). The weird thing is that MSDN states that PictureBox overrides AllowDrop with `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]`, which means it won't show up in Intellisense and it clearly states "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.".  However, I could not get it to work without this workaround!

Comment: It works even without typecast: `myPictureBox.AllowDrop = true;`

Answer (score 1):

```
myPictureBox.AllowDrop = true;
```

You can use this code though you won't see 'AllowDrop' in myPictureBox's method list.